# cpan perl module warning error

Tags: centos, perl, cpan

Trying to install multiple perl modules.

I've already installed cpan and perl via yum on the centos 6 64bit box

I get similar errors as below.

```
  CPAN.pm: Going to build G/GA/GAAS/URI-1.60.tar.gz

Warning: Prerequisite 'Test::More => 0' for 'GAAS/URI-1.60.tar.gz' failed when processing 'RJBS/Test-Simple-1.001002.tar.gz' with 'make => NO'. Continuing, but chances to succeed are limited.
Can't exec "make": No such file or directory at /usr/share/perl5/CPAN/Distribution.pm line 2003.
  GAAS/URI-1.60.tar.gz
  make -- NOT OK
Warning (usually harmless): 'YAML' not installed, will not store persistent state
Running make test
  Can't test without successful make
Running make install
  Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
Running install for module 'LWP::MediaTypes'
'YAML' not installed, falling back to Data::Dumper and Storable to read prefs '/root/.cpan/prefs'
Running make for G/GA/GAAS/LWP-MediaTypes-6.02.tar.gz
Warning: no success downloading '/root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/G/GA/GAAS/LWP-MediaTypes-6.02.tar.gz.tmp2589'. Giving up on it. at /usr/share/perl5/CPAN/Distribution.pm line 379
```

another example

```
[root@server116 ~]# cpan -i YAML
CPAN: Storable loaded ok (v2.20)
Going to read '/root/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Sun, 01 Dec 2013 23:53:03 GMT
Running install for module 'YAML'
CPAN: Data::Dumper loaded ok (v2.124)
'YAML' not installed, falling back to Data::Dumper and Storable to read prefs '/root/.cpan/prefs'
Running make for I/IN/INGY/YAML-0.87.tar.gz
CPAN: Digest::SHA loaded ok (v5.47)
Warning: no success downloading '/root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/I/IN/INGY/CHECKSUMS.tmp1927'. Giving up on it. at /usr/share/perl5/CPAN/Distribution.pm line 1311
  LWP not available

Trying with "/usr/bin/curl -L -f -s -S --netrc-optional" to get
    "http://www.perl.org/CPAN/authors/id/I/IN/INGY/CHECKSUMS"
Checksum for /root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/I/IN/INGY/YAML-0.87.tar.gz ok
YAML-0.87/
YAML-0.87/t/
YAML-0.87/t/load-works.t
YAML-0.87/t/errors.t
YAML-0.87/t/svk-config.yaml
YAML-0.87/t/dump-tests-512.t
YAML-0.87/t/freeze-thaw.t
YAML-0.87/t/dump-file.t
YAML-0.87/t/global-api.t
YAML-0.87/t/test.t
YAML-0.87/t/basic-tests.t
YAML-0.87/t/load-slides.t
YAML-0.87/t/bugs-rt.t
YAML-0.87/t/load-passes.t
YAML-0.87/t/long-quoted-value.yaml
YAML-0.87/t/dump-file-utf8.t
YAML-0.87/t/load-tests.t
YAML-0.87/t/dump-code.t
YAML-0.87/t/dump-stringify.t
YAML-0.87/t/dump-perl-types-512.t
YAML-0.87/t/dump-perl-types.t
YAML-0.87/t/dump-basics.t
YAML-0.87/t/dump-perl-types-514.t
YAML-0.87/t/pugs-objects.t
YAML-0.87/t/svk.t
YAML-0.87/t/dump-blessed.t
YAML-0.87/t/dump-synopsis.t
YAML-0.87/t/node-info.t
YAML-0.87/t/dump-tests-514.t
YAML-0.87/t/changes.t
YAML-0.87/t/Base.pm
YAML-0.87/t/dump-tests.t
YAML-0.87/t/TestYAML.pm
YAML-0.87/t/load-fails.t
YAML-0.87/t/2-scalars.t
YAML-0.87/t/export.t
YAML-0.87/t/dump-opts.t
YAML-0.87/t/bugs-emailed.t
YAML-0.87/t/dump-works.t
YAML-0.87/t/references.t
YAML-0.87/t/inbox.t
YAML-0.87/t/rt-90593.t
YAML-0.87/t/load-spec.t
YAML-0.87/t/regexp.t
YAML-0.87/t/marshall.t
YAML-0.87/t/dump-nested.t
YAML-0.87/LICENSE
YAML-0.87/META.yml
YAML-0.87/Changes
YAML-0.87/lib/
YAML-0.87/lib/Test/
YAML-0.87/lib/Test/YAML.pm
YAML-0.87/lib/YAML.pm
YAML-0.87/lib/YAML/
YAML-0.87/lib/YAML/Types.pm
YAML-0.87/lib/YAML/Dumper.pm
YAML-0.87/lib/YAML/Any.pm
YAML-0.87/lib/YAML/Node.pm
YAML-0.87/lib/YAML/Loader.pm
YAML-0.87/lib/YAML/Error.pm
YAML-0.87/lib/YAML/Dumper/
YAML-0.87/lib/YAML/Dumper/Base.pm
YAML-0.87/lib/YAML/Tag.pm
YAML-0.87/lib/YAML/Loader/
YAML-0.87/lib/YAML/Loader/Base.pm
YAML-0.87/lib/YAML/Marshall.pm
YAML-0.87/lib/YAML/Mo.pm
YAML-0.87/Makefile.PL
YAML-0.87/MANIFEST
YAML-0.87/README
YAML-0.87/inc/
YAML-0.87/inc/Test/
YAML-0.87/inc/Test/Builder.pm
YAML-0.87/inc/Test/Builder/
YAML-0.87/inc/Test/Builder/Module.pm
YAML-0.87/inc/Test/Base.pm
YAML-0.87/inc/Test/More.pm
YAML-0.87/inc/Test/Base/
YAML-0.87/inc/Test/Base/Filter.pm
YAML-0.87/inc/Module/
YAML-0.87/inc/Module/Install/
YAML-0.87/inc/Module/Install/Include.pm
YAML-0.87/inc/Module/Install/Can.pm
YAML-0.87/inc/Module/Install/Fetch.pm
YAML-0.87/inc/Module/Install/Base.pm
YAML-0.87/inc/Module/Install/GithubMeta.pm
YAML-0.87/inc/Module/Install/Win32.pm
YAML-0.87/inc/Module/Install/Makefile.pm
YAML-0.87/inc/Module/Install/WriteAll.pm
YAML-0.87/inc/Module/Install/Metadata.pm
YAML-0.87/inc/Module/Install/Package.pm
YAML-0.87/inc/Module/Install.pm
YAML-0.87/inc/Module/Package.pm
YAML-0.87/inc/Spiffy.pm
CPAN: File::Temp loaded ok (v0.22)

  CPAN.pm: Going to build I/IN/INGY/YAML-0.87.tar.gz

Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Warning: prerequisite ExtUtils::MakeMaker 6.59 not found. We have 6.5502.
Writing Makefile for YAML
Could not read '/root/.cpan/build/YAML-0.87-mpJG64/META.yml'. Falling back to other methods to determine prerequisites
---- Unsatisfied dependencies detected during ----
----           INGY/YAML-0.87.tar.gz          ----
    ExtUtils::MakeMaker [requires]
Shall I follow them and prepend them to the queue
of modules we are processing right now? [yes] 
Running make test
  Delayed until after prerequisites
Running make install
  Delayed until after prerequisites
Running install for module 'ExtUtils::MakeMaker'
'YAML' not installed, falling back to Data::Dumper and Storable to read prefs '/root/.cpan/prefs'
Running make for B/BI/BINGOS/ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84.tar.gz
Warning: no success downloading '/root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/B/BI/BINGOS/ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84.tar.gz.tmp1927'. Giving up on it. at /usr/share/perl5/CPAN/Distribution.pm line 379

Trying with "/usr/bin/curl -L -f -s -S --netrc-optional" to get
    "http://www.perl.org/CPAN/authors/id/B/BI/BINGOS/ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84.tar.gz"
Warning: no success downloading '/root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/B/BI/BINGOS/CHECKSUMS.tmp1927'. Giving up on it. at /usr/share/perl5/CPAN/Distribution.pm line 1311

Trying with "/usr/bin/curl -L -f -s -S --netrc-optional" to get
    "http://www.perl.org/CPAN/authors/id/B/BI/BINGOS/CHECKSUMS"
Checksum for /root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/B/BI/BINGOS/ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84.tar.gz ok
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/MANIFEST.SKIP
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/NOTES
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/META.yml
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/build_man.t
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/recurs.t
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/is_of_type.t
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/MM_OS2.t
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/echo.t
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/META_for_testing.json
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/INST_PREFIX.t
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/prefixify.t
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/prereq_print.t
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/pod2man.t
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/config.t
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/00compile.t
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/miniperl.t
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/lib/
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/lib/TieOut.pm
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/lib/TieIn.pm
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/lib/Test/
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/lib/Test/More.pm
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/lib/Test/Builder/
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/lib/Test/Builder/Module.pm
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/lib/Test/Builder/IO/
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/lib/Test/Builder/IO/Scalar.pm
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/lib/Test/Simple.pm
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/lib/Test/Builder.pm
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/lib/MakeMaker/
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/lib/MakeMaker/Test/
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/lib/MakeMaker/Test/Utils.pm
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/lib/MakeMaker/Test/Setup/
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/lib/MakeMaker/Test/Setup/Problem.pm
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/lib/MakeMaker/Test/Setup/PL_FILES.pm
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/lib/MakeMaker/Test/Setup/MPV.pm
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/lib/MakeMaker/Test/Setup/XS.pm
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/lib/MakeMaker/Test/Setup/BFD.pm
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/lib/MakeMaker/Test/Setup/Recurs.pm
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/lib/MakeMaker/Test/Setup/SAS.pm
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/lib/MakeMaker/Test/NoXS.pm
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/dir_target.t
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/testlib.t
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/MakeMaker_Parameters.t
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/arch_check.t
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/problems.t
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/prereq.t
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/FIRST_MAKEFILE.t
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/MM_NW5.t
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/several_authors.t
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/MM_Win32.t
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/metafile_data.t
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/MM_Unix.t
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/test_boilerplate.t
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/parse_version.t
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/revision.t
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/cd.t
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/fixin.t
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/make.t
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/fix_libs.t
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/PL_FILES.t
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/writemakefile_args.t
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/prompt.t
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/basic.t
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/oneliner.t
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/WriteEmptyMakefile.t
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/MM_VMS.t
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/hints.t
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/testdata/
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/testdata/reallylongdirectoryname/
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/testdata/reallylongdirectoryname/arch2/
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/testdata/reallylongdirectoryname/arch2/Config.pm
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/testdata/reallylongdirectoryname/arch1/
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/testdata/reallylongdirectoryname/arch1/Config.pm
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/MM_Any.t
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/META_for_testing_tricky_version.yml
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/backwards.t
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/Liblist.t
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/maketext_filter.t
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/Liblist_Kid.t
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/installed_file.t
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/pm_to_blib.t
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/INSTALL_BASE.t
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/parse_abstract.t
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/Mkbootstrap.t
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/split_command.t
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/MM_BeOS.t
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/VERSION_FROM.t
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/liblist/
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/liblist/win32/
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/liblist/win32/vc/
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/liblist/win32/vc/vctest.lib
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/liblist/win32/lib/
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/liblist/win32/lib/CORE/
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/liblist/win32/lib/CORE/c_test.lib
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/liblist/win32/lib/CORE/double.lib
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/liblist/win32/imp.dll.a
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/liblist/win32/test.a.lib
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/liblist/win32/test.meep
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/liblist/win32/libpath/
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/liblist/win32/libpath/lp_test.lib
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/liblist/win32/test.lib
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/liblist/win32/lib__test.lib
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/liblist/win32/space lib.lib
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/liblist/win32/di r/
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/liblist/win32/di r/dir_test.lib
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/liblist/win32/double.lib
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/liblist/win32/pl.lib
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/liblist/win32/test2.lib
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/liblist/win32/__test.lib
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/liblist/win32/lib_test.lib
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/liblist/win32/dir/
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/liblist/win32/dir/dir_test.lib
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/pm.t
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/INST.t
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/MM_Cygwin.t
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/postamble.t
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/xs.t
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/metafile_file.t
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/min_perl_version.t
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/META_for_testing.yml
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/01perl_bugs.t
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/t/meta_convert.t
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/lib/
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/lib/ExtUtils/
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/lib/ExtUtils/MM_UWIN.pm
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/lib/ExtUtils/Liblist.pm
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/lib/ExtUtils/MM_Win32.pm
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/lib/ExtUtils/MM_NW5.pm
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/lib/ExtUtils/MM_Darwin.pm
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/lib/ExtUtils/MY.pm
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/lib/ExtUtils/Mkbootstrap.pm
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/lib/ExtUtils/MakeMaker.pm
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/lib/ExtUtils/MM_Any.pm
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/lib/ExtUtils/MM_AIX.pm
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/lib/ExtUtils/MM.pm
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/lib/ExtUtils/Liblist/
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/lib/ExtUtils/Liblist/Kid.pm
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/lib/ExtUtils/testlib.pm
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/lib/ExtUtils/Command/
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/lib/ExtUtils/Command/MM.pm
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/lib/ExtUtils/MM_Unix.pm
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/lib/ExtUtils/MM_Win95.pm
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/lib/ExtUtils/MM_MacOS.pm
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/lib/ExtUtils/MM_OS2.pm
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/lib/ExtUtils/MM_QNX.pm
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/lib/ExtUtils/MM_BeOS.pm
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/lib/ExtUtils/MM_VOS.pm
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/lib/ExtUtils/MM_Cygwin.pm
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/lib/ExtUtils/Mksymlists.pm
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/lib/ExtUtils/MM_DOS.pm
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/lib/ExtUtils/MM_VMS.pm
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/lib/ExtUtils/MakeMaker/
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/lib/ExtUtils/MakeMaker/Config.pm
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/lib/ExtUtils/MakeMaker/FAQ.pod
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/lib/ExtUtils/MakeMaker/Tutorial.pod
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/Makefile.PL
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/TODO
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/META.json
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/bin/
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/bin/instmodsh
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/bundled/
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/bundled/JSON-PP-Compat5006/
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/bundled/JSON-PP-Compat5006/JSON/
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/bundled/JSON-PP-Compat5006/JSON/PP/
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/bundled/JSON-PP-Compat5006/JSON/PP/Compat5006.pm
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/bundled/File-Temp/
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/bundled/File-Temp/File/
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/bundled/File-Temp/File/Temp.pm
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/bundled/version/
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/bundled/version/version/
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/bundled/version/version/vpp.pm
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/bundled/version/version/Internals.pod
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/bundled/version/version.pod
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/bundled/version/version.pm
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/bundled/ExtUtils-Install/
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/bundled/ExtUtils-Install/ExtUtils/
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/bundled/ExtUtils-Install/ExtUtils/Packlist.pm
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/bundled/ExtUtils-Install/ExtUtils/Installed.pm
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/bundled/ExtUtils-Install/ExtUtils/Install.pm
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/bundled/JSON-PP/
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/bundled/JSON-PP/JSON/
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/bundled/JSON-PP/JSON/PP.pm
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/bundled/JSON-PP/JSON/PP/
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/bundled/JSON-PP/JSON/PP/Boolean.pm
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/bundled/CPAN-Meta-YAML/
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/bundled/CPAN-Meta-YAML/CPAN/
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/bundled/CPAN-Meta-YAML/CPAN/Meta/
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/bundled/CPAN-Meta-YAML/CPAN/Meta/YAML.pm
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/bundled/ExtUtils-Manifest/
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/bundled/ExtUtils-Manifest/ExtUtils/
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/bundled/ExtUtils-Manifest/ExtUtils/MANIFEST.SKIP
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/bundled/ExtUtils-Manifest/ExtUtils/Manifest.pm
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/bundled/ExtUtils-Command/
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/bundled/ExtUtils-Command/ExtUtils/
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/bundled/ExtUtils-Command/ExtUtils/Command.pm
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/bundled/CPAN-Meta/
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/bundled/CPAN-Meta/CPAN/
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/bundled/CPAN-Meta/CPAN/Meta.pm
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/bundled/CPAN-Meta/CPAN/Meta/
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/bundled/CPAN-Meta/CPAN/Meta/History.pm
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/bundled/CPAN-Meta/CPAN/Meta/Feature.pm
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/bundled/CPAN-Meta/CPAN/Meta/Prereqs.pm
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/bundled/CPAN-Meta/CPAN/Meta/Spec.pm
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/bundled/CPAN-Meta/CPAN/Meta/Requirements.pm
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/bundled/CPAN-Meta/CPAN/Meta/Validator.pm
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/bundled/CPAN-Meta/CPAN/Meta/Converter.pm
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/bundled/File-Copy-Recursive/
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/bundled/File-Copy-Recursive/File/
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/bundled/File-Copy-Recursive/File/Copy/
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/bundled/File-Copy-Recursive/File/Copy/Recursive.pm
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/bundled/Parse-CPAN-Meta/
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/bundled/Parse-CPAN-Meta/Parse/
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/bundled/Parse-CPAN-Meta/Parse/CPAN/
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/bundled/Parse-CPAN-Meta/Parse/CPAN/Meta.pm
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/bundled/Scalar-List-Utils/
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/bundled/Scalar-List-Utils/List/
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/bundled/Scalar-List-Utils/List/Util.pm
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/bundled/Scalar-List-Utils/List/Util/
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/bundled/Scalar-List-Utils/List/Util/PP.pm
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/bundled/Scalar-List-Utils/Scalar/
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/bundled/Scalar-List-Utils/Scalar/Util.pm
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/bundled/Scalar-List-Utils/Scalar/Util/
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/bundled/Scalar-List-Utils/Scalar/Util/PP.pm
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/bundled/README
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/MANIFEST
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/PATCHING
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/INSTALL
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/Changes
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/my/
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/my/bundles.pm
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/README
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/README.packaging
ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84/.perlcriticrc

  CPAN.pm: Going to build B/BI/BINGOS/ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84.tar.gz

Using included version of Parse::CPAN::Meta (1.4405) because it is not already installed.
Using included version of File::Copy::Recursive (0.38) because it is not already installed.
Using included version of JSON::PP (2.27203) because it is not already installed.
Using included version of CPAN::Meta::YAML (0.008) because it is not already installed.
Using included version of JSON::PP::Compat5006 (1.09) because it is not already installed.
Using included version of ExtUtils::Manifest (1.60) as it is newer than the installed version (1.56).
Using included version of CPAN::Meta (2.120351) because it is not already installed.
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for ExtUtils::MakeMaker
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
Could not read '/root/.cpan/build/ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84-ldgreA/MYMETA.yml'. Falling back to other methods to determine prerequisites
  BINGOS/ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84.tar.gz
  make -- NOT OK
Warning (usually harmless): 'YAML' not installed, will not store persistent state
Running make test
  Can't test without successful make
Running make install
  Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
Running make for I/IN/INGY/YAML-0.87.tar.gz
  Has already been unwrapped into directory /root/.cpan/build/YAML-0.87-mpJG64

  CPAN.pm: Going to build I/IN/INGY/YAML-0.87.tar.gz

Warning: Prerequisite 'ExtUtils::MakeMaker => 6.59' for 'INGY/YAML-0.87.tar.gz' failed when processing 'BINGOS/ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.84.tar.gz' with 'make => NO'. Continuing, but chances to succeed are limited.
  INGY/YAML-0.87.tar.gz
  make -- NOT OK
Warning (usually harmless): 'YAML' not installed, will not store persistent state
Running make test
  Can't test without successful make
Running make install
  Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
```

Comment: Most of those modules are already packaged and in the base repositories. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I need to install all these perl modules. CGI LWP::UserAgent HTTP::Cookies HTML::Entities URI::URL URI::Escape WWW::Mechanize
I installed centos minimal iso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're already over your head with a simple error message as "Can't exec "make": No such file or directory at /usr/share/perl5/CPAN/Distribution.pm line 2003.", then the best advice we can give is to hire someone who know what he is doing.

And all those packages are available in the default CentOS yum repositories. Install them with yum:

```
yum install 'perl(CGI)' 'perl(LWP::UserAgent)'
```

etc...

Comment: Really not a very helpful answer, @ServerSideX came here for help, if everyone knew how to do what they were asking then this website wouldn't need to exist. 

I get that knowing a make dependency error when you see one is pretty "linux 101", but if you're new to linux then you won't know the old-world compilation pains and have likely only been working with package managers (cpan is not a proper package management system). Code compilation errors may seem a bit alien to those who now learn with the benefit of technological advances we had to deal without.